# How are pgf-keys stored and is it possible to print a list of them

Tags: programming, pgfkeys, key-value

I was wondering how pgf-keys are handled internally. For example:
If I define:

```
\pgfkeys{/A/.code={My Key}}
```

and I call the key with

```
Hello this is \pgfkeys{/A}.
```

How does the `\pgfkeys`-command expand?
Which strategy does it use to save so many variables, code snippets, styles etc. Does it use external files? Like a list?
For me it seems, as if the pgf-Layer adds a whole new programming language on top of (La)TeX. And it's hard for me to believe that somebody programmed this with pure (La)TeX.

Furthermore it would be interesting for me, weather or not it is possible to list all the pgf-keys, that are used in a document. For example:

```
\pgfkeys{/hello/.code={foo}, /myfamily/mykey/.code={bar}, /myfamily/mysecondkey/.code={bar2}}
```

should lead to something like

```
hello
myfamily
  |- mykey
  |- mysecondkey
```

or similar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, pgf keys do not use a list, these are just clever uses of TeX macros. I do not think that there is an easy way to get a complete list of pgf keys. However, if you have enough motivation you may modify [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488798/121799) to do that.

Comment: The code for PGF is available on GitHub (and probably is locally installed on your machine). So you do not need to believe anyone that it is written in TeX but you can easily check ;)

Comment: There is some debugging tools for pgfkeys and essentially it works like the `\tracingmacros1` but is for pgfkeys.